# Condition for convergence almost uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. $(f_n)$ and $f$ measurable functions and, for $\epsilon >0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$: $$D_k(\epsilon):=\{x\in X: |f_k(x)-f(x)|\ge\epsilon\}.$$

We suppose that for each $\epsilon >0$, $\displaystyle\mu\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}D_k(\epsilon)\right)\to 0$.

And we have to prove that $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly.

Let $\delta >0$. I want to find $E_{\delta}\in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(E_\delta)<\delta$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X\setminus E_{\delta}$.

Of course I thought that some $\bigcup_{k\ge n}D_k(\epsilon)$ has measure less that $\delta$, but what $\epsilon$ could we take?

Can you give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0.$ For each $m$ there exists $n_m$ such that

$$\mu (\cup_{k=n_m}^\infty\ \{|f_k-f|>1/m\}) < \epsilon/2^m.$$

The union of all those sets has $\mu$-measure $<\epsilon.$ Now think about the complement of that union.

Comment: It worked. Thank you @zhw.